# How to overcome slowness of live camera view in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, image-segmentation, coreml

I am trying to develop an image segmentation app and process the live camera view in my coreml model. However I see some slowness on the output. Camera view with masked prediction is slower. Below is my vision manager class to predict the pixelbuffer and function calling this class to convert to colors before proceed to camera output. Anyone facing this issue before? Do you see an error in my code causing slowness?

Vision Manager Class:

```
class VisionManager: NSObject {
static let shared = VisionManager()
static let MODEL = ba_224_segm().model

private lazy var predictionRequest: VNCoreMLRequest = {
    do{
        let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: VisionManager.MODEL)
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model)
        request.imageCropAndScaleOption = VNImageCropAndScaleOption.centerCrop
        return request
    } catch {
        fatalError("can't load Vision ML Model")
    }
}()

func predict(pixelBuffer: CVImageBuffer, sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, onResult: ((_ observations: [VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation]) -> Void)) {
    var requestOptions: [VNImageOption: Any] = [:]
    if let cameraIntrinsicData = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, key: kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, attachmentModeOut: nil) {
        requestOptions = [.cameraIntrinsics: cameraIntrinsicData]
    }
    
    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: requestOptions)
    do {
        try handler.perform([predictionRequest])
    } catch {
        print("error handler")
    }

    guard let observations = predictionRequest.results as? [VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation] else {
        fatalError("unexpected result type from VNCoreMLRequest")
    }
    onResult(observations)
}
```

Predicted Camera Output function:

```
func handleCameraOutput(pixelBuffer: CVImageBuffer, sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, onFinish: @escaping ((_ image: UIImage?) -> Void)) {
    VisionManager.shared.predict(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer) { [weak self ] (observations) in
        
        if let multiArray: MLMultiArray = observations[0].featureValue.multiArrayValue {
            
            mask = maskEdit.maskToRGBA(maskArray: MultiArray<Float32>(multiArray), rgba: (Float(r),Float(g),Float(b),Float(a)))!
            maskInverted = maskEdit.maskToRGBAInvert(maskArray: MultiArray<Float32>(multiArray), rgba: (r: 1.0, g: 1.0, b:1.0, a: 0.4))!
           
            
            let image = maskEdit.mergeMaskAndBackground( invertedMask: maskInverted, mask: mask, background: pixelBuffer, size: Int(size))
            
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                onFinish(image)
            }
        }
    }
```

I call these models under viwDidAppear as below:

```
        CameraManager.shared.setDidOutputHandler { [weak self] (output, pixelBuffer, sampleBuffer, connection) in
            
            self!.maskColor.getRed(&self!.r, green:&self!.g, blue:&self!.b, alpha:&self!.a)
            self!.a = 0.5
            self?.handleCameraOutput(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, onFinish: { (image) in
            
         
            self?.predictionView.image = image
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out my issue about not using different thread. Since I am new developer I don't know such details and still learning thanks to experts in the field and their shared knowledge. Please see my old and new captureOutput function. To use a different thread solved my problem:

old status:

```
    public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        else { return }


    self.handler?(output, pixelBuffer, sampleBuffer, connection)

    self.onCapture?(pixelBuffer, sampleBuffer)
    self.onCapture = nil

}
```

and new status:

```
    public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                          from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if currentBuffer == nil{
let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    
currentBuffer = pixelBuffer
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

    self.handler?(output, self.currentBuffer!, sampleBuffer, connection)
    
self.currentBuffer = nil

        }
        
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It takes time for your model to perform the segmentation, and then it takes time to convert the output into an image. There is not much you can do to make this delay shorter, except for making the model smaller and making sure the output -> image conversion code is as fast as possible.

Comment: I have figured out what was my mistake thanks to your ebook called "coreML survival guide" in page 53. I had not used separate thread before. Now I call my prediction inside DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async{} .Now it is much faster. CPU load dropped from 100% to 68%. 